# what exactly is file format that looks like b'\x1f\x8b\.....'

Tags: python, file

When I get a file from aws s3 I get it in format as follows:

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x0e@\xfd[\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

What exactly is this?

Also when getting data -unzip - upload back to s3 it can be done by using:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', use_ssl=False)  
s3.upload_fileobj(
    Fileobj = gzip.GzipFile(
                None,
                'rb',
                fileobj=BytesIO(s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=gzipped_key)['Body'].read())),
    Bucket=bucket,
    Key=uncompressed_key)
```

I get `b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x0e@\xfd[\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` when I run `s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket)` line but why wrap that around `BytesIO`?

Comment: @Sid which part is not clear...?

Comment: I'd say "what about BytesIO ?" is a little unclear. It is not clear to me how that relates to the question at all. I'm not sure if you meant "How can I create output like this using BytesIO?" or "Could this have been created using BytesIO?" or something else altogether.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What exactly is this?

`[0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08]` is the header for a `gzip` file. I suggest you run it through `gzip` or open it with something like `7zip` to examine its contents.

> What about BytesIO?

Good question. Unfortunately there's nowhere *near* enough information in that question to give you a *concise* answer. If you wanted a 5000-word essay on `BytesIO` and how it all works, I'd be happy to oblige, but this probably isn't the right place for it :-)

---

On a more serious note, you may want to narrow your area of interest down to something a little more specific. In addition, it's usually a good idea to limit questions to *one* question, since that makes StackOverflow much easier to search/manage.

Comment: Probably worth commenting on how you knew this. I found it out by doing `echo -e '\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x0e@\xfd[\x00\x03\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' | file -` on linux, which output `/dev/stdin: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Tue Nov 27 21:01:02 2018`.

Comment: When I open using gzip.open(file, 'rt', encoding='utf-8) it is giving me utf-8 cannot decode byte. How can I open to see my original file

Comment: You open with `rb` and obviously then without an `encoding` keyword. Without the `b` you are saying "I expect this to be text in a particular encoding" (UTF-8 if you don't say which one). Maybe this is when you need to stop and read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: Perhaps [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) is closer to what you immediately need, actually.